# In maven, add a folder as a source folder but dont include it in source jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a use case where I need to include a folder target/schemas as a source folder using maven-buildHelper plugin. I am generating a war for this project. When the source jar get created, the content of target/schemas also exists in that. I dont want add the content of target/schemas into my source jar. How can it be achieved ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>***************</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>identity</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <dependencies>
       ...............
   </dependencies>

  <build>
     <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>attach-sources</id>
              <phase>verify</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
           <warName>identity</warName>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>unpack</id>
              <phase>prepare-package</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>unpack</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                       <groupId>***************</groupId>
                       <artifactId>authentication-service</artifactId>
                       <version>${project.version}</version>
                       <classifier>sources</classifier>
                       <type>jar</type>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/schemas</outputDirectory>
                       <includes>**/*.java,**/*.xml</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                       <groupId>***************</groupId>
                       <artifactId>authorization-service</artifactId>
                       <version>${project.version}</version>
                       <classifier>sources</classifier>
                       <type>jar</type>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/schemas</outputDirectory>
                       <includes>**/*.java,**/*.xml</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                 </artifactItems>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.plugin.buildHelper}</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>add-source</id>
              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>add-source</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/schemas</source>
                 </sources>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.plugin.jaxb2}</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>schemagen-combined</id>
              <goals>
                 <goal>schemagen</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>prepare-package</phase>
              <configuration>
                 <includes>
                    <include>***************/core/identity/domain/*.java</include>
                    <include>***************/authentication/domain/*.java</include>
                    <include>***************/authorization/domain/*.java</include>
                 </includes>
                 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/schemas</outputDirectory>
                 <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generateDirectory>
              </configuration>
           </execution>

        </executions>
     </plugin
  </plugins>
```

I have a web project identity which depends on two jar authentication and authorization. In project identity, I am generating xsd using jaxb2-maven-plugin for authentication, authorization and identity sources. As the plugin jaxb2-maven-plugin, works only on sources exists in the maven source path, I am downloading sources for authentication and authorization in a folder target/schema, add this folder target/schema as a maven source folder and then running jaxb2-maven-plugin to generate xsd. Now, when I build source jar for identity, it also includes sources for authentication and authorization which I dont want.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Adding a folder as a source folder does what it says. It adds it. Why do you need it as a source folder, but don't need it in the generated artifact?

Comment: Have you tried to use the test resources folder? http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: I have a web project identity which depends on two jar AuthN and AuthZ. In project identity, I am generating xsd using jaxb2-maven-plugin for AuthN and AuthZ sources. As the plugin jaxb2-maven-plugin, works only on sources exists in the maven source path, I am downloading sources for AuthN and AuthZ in a folder target/schema, add this folder target/schema as a maven source folder and then running jaxb2-maven-plugin to generate xsd. Now, when I build source jar for identity, it also inculdes sources for AuthN and AuthZ which I dont want.

Answer (score 1):

[Maven Source plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin) has option for excluding selected files from created source JAR.

> [**exclude**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html#excludes)
>
> List of files to exclude. Specified as fileset patterns which are relative to the input directory whose contents is being packaged into the JAR.

Comment: I'm really tempted to downvote this; you should never generate files into source folders!

Comment: Hmm, you are right, wait a moment, fix is comming :)

Comment: I have tried couple of fileset options but does not seem to help.      <configuration><excludes>
                <exclude>target/schemas/**/*.java</exclude>
              </excludes>
</configuration>

Comment: Try `**/schemas/**/*.java`

Comment: Post pom.xml and full log